# Is there a better way to remove a last subview from view

Tags: objective-c, uiview

To remove last subview from a view, I use

```
[[[self.view subviews] lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
```

I'd use `removeLastObject`, but can't as `subviews` is readonly immutable array.

So I need to:

- access all subviews
- get last object
- call method on it to remove it from superview

It works, but is there a better way? This seem to be a bit unnatural. I look for something like  `[self.view removeLastSubview]`, but unfortunately it doesn't exist.

Comment: @trojanfoe this works, but I think it is a better way. It looks a bit unnatural.

Comment: You are doing it properly. for unnatural - welcome to Objective-C :)

Comment: No, it really is fine that way. Calling `subviews` and `lastObject` is really inexpensive and `removeFromSuperview` must be done anyway.

Comment: oops, I tried to add "[on hold]" and it got added... So I removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid Objective-C's message-sending syntax

<sub>Note: dont do that</sub>

```
UIView *lastView = self.view.subviews[self.view.subviews.count-1];
lastView.removeFromSuperview;
```

<sub>I said: dont do that</sub>

but seriously:

```
[[[self.view subviews] lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
```

is just fine. I'd consider the first snippet code-smell.

Answer (score 1):

Make a category

```
@interface UIView (Exptened)

- (void)removeLastSubView;

@end

@implementation UIView(Exptened)

- (void)removeLastSubView
{
    [[[self subviews] lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
}

@end
```